# Add User Control after I Disposed It

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm closing usercontrol1 by disposing of it and I need to add it again programmatically in my form1. usercontrol1 will only be added back to form1 after I close usercontrol2 which sends an event to form1 to add usercontrol1 again in a panel. I know how to do sending and receiving of events but what I do not know is how to add usercontrol1 again because it seems my instantiation of usercontrol1 in form1 is just being ignored after I disposed of usercontrol1. Additionally, I'm using .Dispose() because I want to trigger the Load event of usercontrol1 everytime I call it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Create a method that will be called to create the desired control, so after yu dispose it, you can call it back again.

Comment: And this is not a well-written question.

Comment: Also, what are those usercontrols? BE specific, is it a panel since it closes or something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You create a new instance of UserControl1 (or whatever your usercontrol type is) and then add it to the panel.

```
public void MyTriggeringEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 usercontrol1 = new UserControl1();
    panel1.Controls.Add(usercontrol1);
}
```

MyTriggeringEvent is the event you're handling where you want to re-add usercontrol1.

Though there is a far easier way of achieving what you want without removing and re-adding usercontrol1.

Your `usercontrol1` has code like this:

```
public void usercontrol1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Lots of initialization code here
}
```

Instead of leaving your init code in the Load event handler move it to its own method then call that method from the Load event handler and in your MyTriggeringEvent call that same method:

This code goes in usercontrol1:

```
public void MyInitCode()
{
    // Lots of initialization code here
}

public void usercontrol1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyInitCode();
}
```

This code goes in your form where you handle the event:

```
public void MyTriggeringEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    usercontrol1.MyInitCode();
}
```